CASE in a multiple select query
I'm running the below query which works fine but I want to add in a further change. I've been looking at trying to use CASE to give me a better description from opt.oper_type but I'm unsure if I can embed this in to my select query.
select 
oc.card_number,
opt.oper_date as "TRANSACTION_DATE",
op.account_number, 
vf.sttl_currency as "SOURCE_AMOUNT_CURRENCY", 
vf.sttl_amount as "SOURCE_AMOUNT", 
op.auth_code, 
opt.mcc, 
opt.terminal_number as "TERMINAL_ID", 
vf.pos_terminal_cap, 
vf.pos_entry_mode, 
opt.oper_type, 
opt.part_key as "CAPTURE_DATE", 
opt.oper_amount as "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT",
opt.oper_currency as "TRANSACTION_CURRENCY", 
opt.merchant_name, 
opt.merchant_country, 
opt.clearing_sequence_num, 
opt.clearing_sequence_count
    from opr_operation opt, opr_participant op, opr_card oc , vis_fin_message vf 
    where
        op.oper_id=opt.id 
        and opt.id =vf.id
        and opt.clearing_sequence_num > 1 
        and opt.part_key >= '28-MAR-24' 
        and op.card_id= vf.card_id
        and op.participant_type='PRTYISS'
        and oc.oper_id=opt.id
        and opt.msg_type in ('MSGTPAMC','MSGTPACC');

This gives me the following output:
CARD_NUMBER              TRANSACTI ACCOUNT_NUMBER                   SOU SOURCE_AMOUNT AUTH_C MCC  TERMINAL_ID      POS_TERM PO OPER_TYP CAPTURE_D TRANSACTION_AMOUNT TRA MERCHANT_NAME                                                                                                                                                                                            MER CLEARING_SEQUENCE_NUM CLEARING_SEQUENCE_COUNT
------------------------ --------- -------------------------------- --- ------------- ------ ---- ---------------- -------- -- -------- --------- ------------------ --- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --- --------------------- -----------------------
****************         28-MAR-24 006000152511                     840          2020 760667 5734 TERMID01         9        01 OPTP0000 02-APR-24               2020 840 ACQUIRER NAME

But I'd like to add a CASE rule in like the one below in to my query to give a further column showing the TransactionType being '05' if it meets the criteria of matching OPTP0000.
select 
oper_type, 
CASE 
    when oper_type = 'OPTP0000' THEN '05' ELSE 'other'
     END AS TransactionType   
     from opr_operation;

OPER_TYP TRANS
-------- -----
OPTP0000 05  

Is this possible at all or is there another way of doing it using something other than CASE? I know my SQL isn't the best but this is only for me to run against some internal test systems so I can easily identify some of the details in there so I apologise in advance.

What happens when you add your case expression to your main query - it looks like it should just work (as you already include that table - though you should use the table alias when referring to the column), so what error or problem did you have?

If the column oper_type occur in more than one table, specify the table name as part of the column reference :
select 
  oc.card_number,
  ...
  opt.clearing_sequence_count,
  case when opt.oper_type = 'OPTP0000' then '05' else 'other' end as TransactionType   
from opr_operation opt, opr_participant op, opr_card oc , vis_fin_message vf 
where
    op.oper_id=opt.id 
    and opt.id =vf.id
    and opt.clearing_sequence_num > 1 
    and opt.part_key >= '28-MAR-24' 
    and op.card_id= vf.card_id
    and op.participant_type='PRTYISS'
    and oc.oper_id=opt.id
    and opt.msg_type in ('MSGTPAMC','MSGTPACC');

